# How to monitor Resque::DirtyExit error in Resque gem worker/child processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78M8Q.png)

In my rails application when this job is processing at that time some OS processes or some other processes are killing my job process so I am getting DirtyErrorExit but I want to enqueue my job again if it gets a DirtyErrorExit  exception. I am also trying to rescue that error inside my job but I am not able to rescue this error. Also I am not getting any logs regarding this DirtyErrorExit error in my application. So is there any way to track this error or rescue this error.